# Copy first word from each line of first file to second file

Tags: shell, copy, vi

I have two files of equal number of lines. I've to take first word of each line in first file and place it at the beginning of each line in second file. I want to know how to do it using vi editor or any other scripting language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `paste`:

```
$ cat file1
one file 1
two file 1
three file 1
four file 1
five file 1

$ cat file2
1 file 2
2 file 2
3 file 2
4 file 2
5 file 2

$ paste -d' ' <(awk '{print $1}' file1) file2
one 1 file 2
two 2 file 2
three 3 file 2
four 4 file 2

# Store changes back to file2
$ paste -d' ' <(awk '{print $1}' file1) file2 > tmp && mv tmp file2
```

If you have an older version of `bash` which doesn't support [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) then you can do:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' file1 | paste -d' ' - file2
one 1 file 2
two 2 file 2
three 3 file 2
four 4 file 2
five 5 file 2
```

You could use `cut -d' ' -f1 file1` instead of `awk '{print $1}' file1`.